# C while doesn't stop

Tags: c, while-loop

I just can't understand why this while is not stopping :

```
int **movePlayer(int playerI,int playerJ,int length,int ***tab)
{
char letter;
int l;
int c =0;
int verif = 0;
int number;
//int c= 0;
while( verif == 0){
    //fflush(stdin);
    printf("Entrez la lettre correspondante à la colonne sur laquelle vous voulez jouer\n");
    scanf(" %c", &letter);
    //fflush(stdin);
    printf("Entrez le chiffre correspondante à la ligne sur laquelle vous voulez jouer\n");
    scanf(" %d", &number);
    verif = verifScan(playerI,playerJ,letter,number,tab,length);
    printf("%d", verif);
    verif = 1;
}
l = (int)letter - 65;
(*tab)[playerI][playerJ] = 'j' ;
(*tab)[number][l] = 'J';
}
```

And I precise that the last printf of verif return 1 because my function verifScan is returning 1 here.

verifScan is here and returns 1 when I write B and 0 in my scanf :

```
int verifScan(int posI,int posJ,int letter, int number,int ***tab,int     length)
{
   int l;
   if(letter >= 97 && letter <= 97 + length - 1){
      l = letter - 97;
      //return 1;
   } else if(letter >= 65 && letter <= 65 + length - 1){
      l = letter - 65;
      //return 1;
   }else {
      return 0;
   }
   if(number > length - 1 || number < 0){
      return 0;
   }
   if(verifCaseLibre(tab,l,number) == 0){
      return 0;
   }

   if((abs(l - posJ) == 0 && abs(number - posI) == 1) || (abs(l - posJ) == 1 && abs(number - posI) == 0))
   {
      return 1;
   }

   return 1;
}
```

[I admet that i have a lots of warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVHJt.png)

Can I have some help please ? Thank you.

Comment: Are you *sure* that `verifScan` really returns what you think it returns? Please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and use that knowledge to find out.

Comment: We won't know until we see the definition of `verifScan`.

Comment: Also, doing `fflush` on an input-only stream (like `stdin`) is explicitly *undefined behavior* in the C specification. Don't do it. There are better ways to skip leading white-space (like adding a leading single space before `%c`).

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` <- this is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: If I remove fflush(stdin), it's ignoring the first scanf and I can't write in my first scanf.

Comment: Please don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If you want to convert an upper-case letter to a lower-case (or the opposite) then use e.g. [`tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower) (or [`toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper)).

Comment: I removed the fflush and It's the same error ...

Comment: Are you sure this is your **exact code**? I'd say it can't be reproduced ... try adding a `verif = 1;` at the end of your loop to be sure.

Comment: Yes, it is and even with verif = 1; the while doesn't stop. It's unbelievable.

Comment: Indeed, I don't believe it :) Sorry, but either you have a buggy compiler (not so likely) or there's some error/typo you didn't reproduce in the code shown in your question. Maybe the problem is **outside** the function you show, so you just call this function repeatedly by mistake.

Comment: A [mcve] could eliminate all doubts and guessing, btw.

Comment: @J.Ternisien ; While `fflush()` is not defined for input streams in the standard, in [Microsoft's implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx) it is well-defined and documented.  I would not encourage its use if code portability is a concern, but it will work.  So if it works for you, I guess you are using Microsoft's library.  Time to learn to use a debugger to see what is going on here - the description lacks plausibility.

Comment: I did a cupy paste so the code is really the same lol. It's crazy if I put another while in my function movePlayer, this another while works !

Comment: The problem isn't in the (part of the) code you show.

Comment: Your function has a return type of `int**` but no `return` statement. Undefined behavior.

Comment: @Blastfurnace which could maybe confuse the (secret ...) calling code into repeatedly calling this function. You could have spotted part of the culprit here :) Clearly, this question is missing a [mcve].

Comment: @J.Ternisien: please precise what you mean with "the loop doesn't stop". What is the exact output you're seeing? Does your code keep asking "Entrez la lettre..."? Are you sure you're not calling `movePlayer()` inside another infinite loop? Try putting a `puts("out of the loop")` at the end of your `while (...) {...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, the problem was finally that I called the function twice so the while was initialize twice. Thank you everyone for helping.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem 1

`fflush` is meant to be used with output streams, not input streams. Use of `fflush(stdin)` is not right. From http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush:

> For input streams (and for update streams on which the last operation was input), the behavior is undefined.

If you want to ignore everything up to the end of the line, you may use:

```
 int c;
 while ( (c = getc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

I recommend putting that in a function and calling the function.

```
 void ignoreLine(FILE* fp)
 {
    int c;
    while ( (c = getc(fp)) != '\n' && c != EOF);
 }
```

and then use

```
 ignoreLine(stdin);
```

#### Problem 2

Use of `"%c"` in the format specifier of a call to `scanf` will not skip whitespaces. If you want to skip whitespaces, use `" %c"`.

```
  scanf(" %c", &letter);
```

---

It's likely that your problem stems from a combination of the above two.

Comment: Tthank you for the answer, I removed the fflush and put " %c" and " %d". But the problem is still here, there is the same problem that I exposed at the beginnig. I precise that I updated my code on top.